# Is “all women who are mothers of daughters” right?

Tags: grammar, numbers

Is the expression

> All women who are mothers of daughters are here.

correct? I mean every woman who has at least one daughter is here.

Comment: I think that the right preposition is "of", "mothers of daughters". Have you seen Game of Thrones and the Mother of Dragons? But I prefer your second sentence best.

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks for your suggestion. But I need a sentence starting with “All women who ... “.

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: @Raj33 is that expression correct?

Comment: To me *(A Non-native English Speaker)*, there is nothing wrong in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All women who are mothers of daughters are here.

It is correct, but it's a bit silly. By definition, a woman who has a daughter is a mother, so instead, you can say

> All women who have a daughter are here

It's still not the most natural way of saying this, but you commented that you should start your sentence with "All women who..." so I assume it's a "fill in the blanks" exercise.

I just noticed that before the edit, you said "mothers for daughters" which means something entirely different. A mother *of* someone is, biologically (or legally) the parent of said person. You can however be a mother *for* someone, without any biological or legal connection. For example, you can say the nanny was like a mother for the kids.

---

With regard to the question in the comments: is it "daughter" or "daughters"? There seems to be no strict rule here; see for example the answers to [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114077/singular-noun-objects-of-plural-subjects). I will motivate either option below.

- Plural (daughters). This follows the general rule: the subject and object have to agree. Indeed, each woman will have their own daughter, which means that more than one daughter is present.
- Singular (daughter). The above *could* be interpreted as "all woman who have more than one daughter". By using the singular form, I emphasise that women who only have a single daughter are also present.

The singular form could in theory be misread as "there was a multitude of polygamous women, who all shared legal parenthood of a single daughter". This may be culture-specific, but most people will not assume this, while some people may assume that parents of a single daughter are excluded from the group. Hence, I chose the singular form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I wonder why you use “a daughter” in your sentence when the subject is “all women”? It seems to be non-consistent.

Comment: Is it correct to say “All women who has a daughter are here?”

Comment: @user150248 See the edit. The verb, in any case, has to agree with the subject, not the object. "All women who has..." is definitely wrong.